# clEnqueueWriteBuffer execution time in a loop

Tags: opencl, amd-gpu

I have an OpenCL code where I invoke `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` and `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` inside a loop multiple time. I measure the data transfer time and the kernel execution time of each loop using `GetLocalTime` function. The issue I am facing is that the `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` and `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` in the first iteration takes much longer to complete than the ones in the second iteration. Why does this happen?

I am working on a system with AMD A10 APU. My OpenCL loop code is:

```c
for(j = 0; j < PARTITION_COUNT; j++){

        //Writing to input buffers
        GetLocalTime(&start);
        clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue[0], buf_A, CL_TRUE, 0, PARTITION_SIZE * sizeof(int), input_A + (PARTITION_SIZE * j), 0, NULL, &eventList[0]);
        checkErr(cl_err, "clEnqueueWriteBuffer : buf_A");
    
        clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue[1], buf_B, CL_TRUE, 0, PARTITION_SIZE * sizeof(int), input_B + (PARTITION_SIZE * j), 0, NULL, &eventList[1]);
        checkErr(cl_err, "clEnqueueWriteBuffer : buf_B");
    
        clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue[2], buf_C, CL_TRUE, 0, PARTITION_SIZE * sizeof(int), input_C + (PARTITION_SIZE * j), 0, NULL, &eventList[2]);
        checkErr(cl_err, "clEnqueueWriteBuffer : buf_C");
    
        clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue[3], buf_D, CL_TRUE, 0, PARTITION_SIZE * sizeof(int), input_D + (PARTITION_SIZE * j), 0, NULL, &eventList[3]);
        checkErr(cl_err, "clEnqueueWriteBuffer : buf_D");

        clFinish(queue[0]);
        clFinish(queue[1]);
        clFinish(queue[2]);
        clFinish(queue[3]);

        //getting end time
        GetLocalTime(&end);
        //displaying final time
        cout<<"\nTime : "<<start.wMinute<<" "<<start.wSecond<<" "<<start.wMilliseconds;
        cout<<"\nTime : "<<end.wMinute<<" "<<end.wSecond<<" "<<end.wMilliseconds;

        GetLocalTime(&start);
        cl_err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue[4],kernel[Q6_PROGRAM_ID][FILTER1_KERNEL],1,NULL,&globalSize,&localSize,4,eventList,&eventList[4]);
        checkErr(cl_err, "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel : filter1_kernel");

        //clFinish(queue[4]);

        //Invoking the second filter kernel
        cl_err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue[5],kernel[Q6_PROGRAM_ID][FILTER2_KERNEL],1,NULL,&globalSize,&localSize,1,eventList + 4,&eventList[5]);
        checkErr(cl_err, "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel : filter2_kernel");

        //clFinish(queue[5]);

        //Invoking the third filter kernel
        cl_err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue[6],kernel[Q6_PROGRAM_ID][FILTER3_KERNEL],1,NULL,&globalSize,&localSize,1,eventList + 5,&eventList[6]);
        checkErr(cl_err, "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel : filter3_kernel");

        //clFinish(queue[6]);

        //Invoking the aggregate kernel
        cl_err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue[8],kernel[Q6_PROGRAM_ID][AGGREGATE_KERNEL],1,NULL,&globalSize,&localSize,1,eventList + 6,&eventList[7]);
        checkErr(cl_err, "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel : aggregate kernel");

        output_A = (int *)clEnqueueMapBuffer(queue[9],output_buf_A,CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, rLen * sizeof(int), 1, eventList + 7, &eventList[8], &cl_err);
        checkErr(cl_err, "clEnqueueReadBuffer : output_A");
    
        

        for(i = 0; i < rLen; i++){
            if(output_A[i] > 0){
                //cout<<"\n"<<output_A[i];
                sum += output_A[i];
            }
            
        }

        clFinish(queue[4]);
        clFinish(queue[5]);
        clFinish(queue[6]);
        clFinish(queue[8]);
        clFinish(queue[9]);

        GetLocalTime(&end);

        //displaying final time
        cout<<"\nTime1 : "<<start.wMinute<<" "<<start.wSecond<<" "<<start.wMilliseconds;
        cout<<"\nTime1 : "<<end.wMinute<<" "<<end.wSecond<<" "<<end.wMilliseconds;

    }

    GetLocalTime(&end1);
    //displaying final time
    cout<<"\nTime2 : "<<start1.wMinute<<" "<<start1.wSecond<<" "<<start1.wMilliseconds;
    cout<<"\nTime2 : "<<end1.wMinute<<" "<<end1.wSecond<<" "<<end1.wMilliseconds;
```

The output is:

```
Time : 27 30 404
  
Time : 27 30 466

Time1 : 27 30 474

Time1 : 27 30 547

Time : 27 30 551

Time : 27 30 555

Time1 : 27 30 561

Time1 : 27 30 582

Time : 27 30 587

Time : 27 30 591

Time1 : 27 30 597

Time1 : 27 30 617

Time : 27 30 622

Time : 27 30 627

Time1 : 27 30 638

Time1 : 27 30 659

Time : 27 30 670

Time : 27 30 675

Time1 : 27 30 679

Time1 : 27 30 699

Time : 27 30 706

Time : 27 30 711

Time1 : 27 30 718

Time1 : 27 30 737

Time2 : 27 30 404

Time2 : 27 30 743

PROGRAM EXECUTION OVER
```

Comment: Profiling of execution should be done using the CL profiling information. Getting the time in CPU side is not accurate, and could account for overhead of initializing OpenCL stuff the first time. Additionally, using blocking calls and clFinish is a very very very very bad idea in OpenCL. Also why do you create a queue for each command? That is also not very friendly at all.

Comment: Hi, i switched to profiling functions and the time output looks better now. Thanks. Why is using clFinish a bad idea? could you please explain?

Comment: clFinish blocks the CPU execution until the Device finishes the task given. Normally you are simply wasting a few ms each time you call clFinish where the Device and Host are idle. You should use blocking read calls (that only wait for their call to complete not the full queue), or events.